# What to do with suspended users in the data dump?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, data-dump, account-suspension

They could be creating strange anomalies when someone does a query against the datadump when someone is suspended when it's generated.

So either remove those users from the dump or include them in their normal state. An example of this from the current dump is the user [Shore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit too much work for a process that is

1. totally free
2. has taken a ton of engineering so far
3. is extremely minor

declining.

Answer (score 3):

My first instinct was to request that a flag be added to the dump to indicate the users that were under suspension, but while this is technically public information, I think that providing a permanent record of their suspension isn't something that we should be doing. And to prevent the artificially low reputation from throwing off the stats, I, too, vote for the normal state option.

Comment: I suspect I could find suspended users already by writing a query for users with 1 rep and sum(score) for their posts > 1

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104095/suspended-users

Comment: That said, this just underscores the need to show the earned rep rather than suspended rep in the next dump.

Answer (score 2):

Removing them could create even more anomalies. I vote for the *normal state* option.

Comment: Aye, since it's also temporary. It will be reverted soon after the data dump is released.